# Aggregate hourly data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table T1 with below data

```
Domain  Mode    Channel  KPI             Value  AvgTm  Rounded_Time
USD     Manual  P1       consolidateUSD  20     2      11/14/2015 12:15:00
USD     Manual  P1       consolidateUSD  10     4      11/14/2015 12:30:00
USD     Manual  P1       consolidateUSD  10     2      11/14/2015 12:45:00
USD     Manual  P1       consolidateUSD  20     4      11/14/2015 13:00:00
DKT     Auto    P2       consolidateDKT  5      4      11/14/2015 12:15:00
DKT     Auto    P2       consolidateDKT  5      4      11/14/2015 12:30:00
DKT     Auto    P2       consolidateDKT  5      4      11/14/2015 12:45:00
DKT     Auto    P2       consolidateDKT  5      4      11/14/2015 13:00:00
```

I need to aggregate data based on "Rounded_Time" and I must get the SUM of "value" and AVG of "AvgTm" and pump into another table T2. This script will be scheduled hourly. So, next time, it must not pick earlier data.

output T2 table has

```
Domain  Mode    Channel  KPI             Value  AvgTm  Rounded_Time
USD     Manual  P1       consolidateUSD  60     3      11/14/2015 13:00
DKT     Auto    P2       consolidateDKT  5      4      11/14/2015 13:00
```

I am not able to get the output properly. I tried the below. I am new to SQL. Please help.

```
select *
from T1
where Rounded_Time interval 60
  and SUM(Value)
  and AVG(AvgTm)
group by Domain, Mode, Channel, KPI
```

Comment: what are the data types of those columns? in particular "Rounded_Time" - is it a string?. Is there no date at all in the columns? (bad idea)

Comment: By the way, are you sure sure that taking an average over 4 data points is an accurate method of summarizing your "average"?

Comment: This time it shall pick 12:15, 12:30, 12:45, and 13:00 and next time 13:15, 13:30, 13:45, and 14:00? So this time the batch runs after 13:00 and before 14:00 and next time it runs after 14:00 and before 15:00? And tomorrow today's records (e.g. 12:15) will be replaced by new ones?

Comment: correct. datatype of "Rounded_Time" is "Date" .

Comment: @tester: It's worth thinking through Used_By_Already's comment; the avarage of sub-avarages is not necessarily the total avarage. AVG(AVG(1,1,1),AVG(5)) = AVG(1,5) = 3, but AVG(1,1,1,5) = 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this perhaps

```
SELECT
      "DOMAIN"
    , "MODE"
    , "CHANNEL"
    , "KPI"
    , TRUNC(ROUNDED_TIME,'HH24') rounded_date
    , to_number(to_char(ROUNDED_TIME,'HH24')) hr_int
    , SUM(Value)
    , AVG(AvgTm)
FROM T1
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY
      "DOMAIN"
    , "MODE"
    , "CHANNEL"
    , "KPI"
    , TRUNC(ROUNDED_TIME,'HH24')
    , to_number(to_char(ROUNDED_TIME,'HH24'))
```

At this stage I don't know what to suggest for the WHERE clause because I would want a date/time reference in the data. Not just some string called rounded_time.

Comment: Datatype of "Rounded_time" is "Date" .

Comment: OK, then we can use TRUNC() then. Will modify the query for this. However you handling of "an hour" is non-standard, normally 12:00:00 through to 12:59:59.999 is the hour 12 not 13 (which starts at 13:00:00)

Comment: It's too late for me I've done what I can for now, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct 
t.channel,  dDomain,mMode,KPI,sum(value1) as sumValue ,sum(AvgTm )  /count(AvgTm) as AvgTm,
x.Rounded_Time
    from 
    (select * from 
    test2
    where 
     Rounded_Time  = current_timestamp - interval  '1' hour )   t
    inner join
    (
select Rounded_Time  ,channel
from test2 
where 
     Rounded_Time  = current_timestamp - interval  '1' hour 
qualify row_number() over(partition by channel order by Rounded_Time desc) =1
) X
    on t.channel = x.channel
    group  by 
t.channel,  dDomain,mMode,KPI,x.Rounded_Time
```

It is using Teradata database..

Answer (score 0):

As you say "correct" to all our assumptions, ...

- you only use the time part of rounded_time and we must ignore the date part
- the batch that shall pick 12:15, 12:30, 12:45, and 13:00 runs after 13:00 and before 14:00

This leads to a WHERE clause like this:

```
where extract(hour from systimestamp) - 1 = 
      extract(hour from cast(rounded_time as timestamp) - interval '1' minute)
```

Here we extract the current hour when the batch is executing the query and subtract one. This would give us 12 for the batch running after 13:00 and before 14:00.

And we take rounded_time, subtract a minute to get from 12:00 to 11:59 and from 13:00 to 12:59, and extract the hour. So we get 12 for all records after 12:00 until 13:00.

The complete query:

```
select 
  domain, mode, channel, kpi,
  sum(value),
  avg(avgtm),
  to_char(sysdate, 'hh24') || ':00'
from t1
where extract(hour from systimestamp) - 1 = 
      extract(hour from cast(rounded_time as timestamp) - interval '1' minute)
group by domain, mode, channel, kpi;
```

Comment: It is not working. It gives error : ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that Oracle implemented EXTRACT so horribly that it cannot extract the time parts from a DATE type (in spite of DATE being Oracle's DATE*TIME*). One must cast to TIMESTAMP to get it working. I've updated my answer.

Comment: its not working. It's not giving value either for "value" nor "avgtm"

Comment: I don't know why. Maybe try this WHERE clause without aggregation first, just to see what records you get?

Comment: ok. But I need to fetch the "rounded_time" as well. But since we are not adding it in the "group by", it throws ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error when i add it. How to solve this issue?.

Comment: *The* rounded_time? There are several records per group, so you can only show an *aggregate*, e.g. the *minimum* or *maximum* rounded_time per group. My query is showing 13:00 for the batch running after 13:00 and before 14:00 collecting data from after 12:00 until 13:00. Just as in your sample output. What *other* "rounded_time" do you want to show?

Comment: Here in your code, you have used "to_char(sysdate, 'hh24') || ':00'" ..  But lets consider if the code did not run at say 13:00 PM, 14:00 PM , but runs at 15:00 PM. The aggregation would be incorrect. could you please correct it to handle dynamically. ie. it should aggregate for all time viz 13:00 PM, 14:00 PM and 15:00 PM

Comment: You said that the batch collecting data from after 12:00 until 13:00 runs after 13:00 and before 14:00. So the hour will be 13, no matter if it runs at 13:00 or 13:59. What could be more dynamical? If the batch runs at 15:01, it is another scope entirely having nothing to do with the before mentioned. A batch running at 15:01 will collect data from after 14:00 and before 15:00 and be labelled with hour 15. I see no flaws in this - unless your answer "correct" was incorrect :-)

Comment: It is a new scope or rather updation Thorsten Kettner. Now, if the script does not run at 12:00 , 13:00  but runs at 14:00, it must agregate indiviadually for 12:00, 13:00 and 14:00 with the same logic that your code performs.  could you help :)

Comment: How is the batch running after 14:00 supposed to know whether the batches after 12:00 and after 13:00 ran or not? It seems you are expecting some magic to take effect here, which is not likely to happen ;-) Obviously you will have to change your concept of determining what data to collect, probably by having your batch store the latest hour it accessed, so the next run will collect from then onwards.

Comment: I have added a new field in my output table named" Process status" . I can set this every time data is loaded hourly. And, I can fetch the time part in "Rounded timestamp" and subtract it from corresponding output table  "Rounded timestamp" and loop it through. But is it achievable in SQL?